# Backbone.js click event not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

View:

```
 Member.Views.Popover = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "member/default",
    tagName: 'a',
    className: 'header-auth member',
    events: {
      'click a.member': 'toggle'
    },        
    initialize: function() {    
      //todo
    },
    toggle: function(){   
      console.log("toggle");
    }
  });
```

Output:

```
<a class="header-auth member">
    //content from template
</a>
```

**First problem:** first I defined just a template without tagName and className because this data was already set in the template. But this wrapped the template with a div. To avoid that I set tagName and className and removed this data from template because now it is set by backbone.

**Second problem:** now that I use tagName the click event does not work anymore.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where are you calling render on the view?

Comment: You can change `click a.member` to merely `click`, since the element is your view.

Comment: @kalley this works^^ make this an answer

Comment: @Matt app.useLayout("main-layout").setViews({
        ".aClass": new Member.Views.Popover({model : this.member })
      }).render(); in main.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You <strike>can</strike> should change `click a.member` to merely `click`, since the element is your view.

Comment: _You can_, no, _You should_.

Comment: ["Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`. ... Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`)."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)